# How to put geometry in a Toplevel in Tkinter?

Tags: python, graph, tkinter, geometry

I'm attempting to make a graph in a Toplevel in Tkinter. I think that the problem is that you can't pack Toplevels in Tkinter and you need to pack canvases before placing geometry (ex: lines, rectangles, etc.). Here's a snipet from a code I'm trying to write (city name is an instance variable in my class):

```
def graph(self):
    print self.cityName
    top = Toplevel(master, width = 300, height = 300)
    top.title(self.cityName + "'s Population")
    top.create_line(10, 300-10, 10, 300)
    top.create_line(10, 300-10, 300-10, 10)
```

It raises an error when it tries to create the line in the 5th line of code. Is there any way to create lines on a Toplevel in python's Tkinter?

This is the error:

> AttributeError: Toplevel instance has no attribute 'create_line'

Comment: Please include the error traceback in the question.

Answer (score 1):

`Toplevel`s do not have a `create_line` method, though `tk.Canvas`s do. So pack a `Canvas` in the `Toplevel` and then draw on the `Canvas`:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
top = tk.Toplevel(root, width = 300, height = 300)
canvas = tk.Canvas(top, bg='white')
canvas.pack(expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)

top.title("Population")
canvas.create_line(10, 300-10, 10, 300)
canvas.create_line(10, 300-10, 300-10, 10)
root.mainloop()
```